# C# - Serializing Packets Over a Network

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, tcp, udp

I am developing a networked application that sends a lot of packets. Currently, my method of serialization is just a hack where it takes a list of objects and converts them into a string delimited by a pipe character '|' and flushes it down the network stream (or just sends it out through UDP).

> I am looking for a cleaner solution to this in C# while minimizing
>   packet size (so no huge XML serialization).

My experiences with `BinaryFormatter is SLOW`.  I am also considering compressing my packets by encoding them into `base64` strings and them decoding them on the client side.  I would like some input on seeing how this will effect the performance of my application.

Also, another quick question:

My setup creates 2 sockets (one `TCP and UDP`) and the client connects individually to these two sockets. Data is flushed down either one based off of the need (TCP for important stuff, UDP for unimportant stuff).  This is my first time using TCP/UDP simultaneously and was wondering

> if there is a more unified method, although it does not seem so.

Thanks as always for the awesome support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a binary protocol similar to [Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).  Using John Skeet's [protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) one can use the WriteDelimitedTo and MergeDelimitedFrom methods on IMessage and IBuilder respectively.  These will prefix the message with the number of bytes so that they can consumed on the other end.  Defining messages are really easy:

```
message MyMessage {
    required int32 number = 1;
}
```

Then you build the C# classes with [ProtoGen.exe](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/wiki/ProtoGen) and just go to town.  One of the big benefits to protobuffers (specifically protobuf-csharp-port) is that not every endpoint needs to be upgraded at the same time.  New fields can be added and consumed by previous versions without error.  This version independence can be very powerful, but can also bite you if you're not planning for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for the serilization

Answer (score 0):

I personally have used following system:
Have abstract Packet class, all packets are derived from. Packet class defines two virtual methods:

```
void SerializeToStream(BinaryWriter serializationStream)
void BuildFromStream(BinaryReader serializationStream)
```

This manual serialization makes it possible to create small sized packets.
Before sending to socket, packets are length prefixed and prefixed with unique packet type id number. Receiving end can then use Activator.CreateInstance to build appropriate packet and call BuildFromStream to reconstruct the packet.

Example packet:

```
class LocationUpdatePacket : Packet
{
   public int X;
   public int Y;
   public int Z;

   public override void SerializeToStream(BinaryWriter serializationStream)
   {
         serializationStream.Write(X);
         serializationStream.Write(Y);
         serializationStream.Write(Z);
   }
   public override void BuildFromStream(BinaryReader serializationStream)
   {
         X = serializationStream.ReadInt32();
         Y = serializationStream.ReadInt32();
         Z = serializationStream.ReadInt32();
   }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I avoided BinaryReader/Writer is because of how slow BinaryFormatter was. Any ideas on the speed of this VS BFormatter?

Answer (score 0):

> I am developing a networked application that sends a lot of packets

Check out [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net), an open source network communication library, might save you a fair bit of time. It incorporates protobuf for serialisation, an example of which is [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/987ff2245685/ExamplesConsole/AdvancedSend.cs), line 408.